# Angular *ngFor not populating any data

Tags: angular, ngfor

```
export class AppComponent {
  pickBtnClicked = false;
  selectedPickNumber: 'string';
  selectedRegion: 'string';
  currentPickSelection: any[];
  channelList: any[];

  constructor(private pickGroupService: PickGroupService, private channelsService: ChannelsService) {}

  onPkClick(btnPicked) {
    this.pickBtnClicked = true;
    this.selectedPickNumber = btnPicked;
  }
  onRegionClick(regionPicked) {
    this.selectedRegion = regionPicked;
    this.currentPickSelection = this.pickGroupService.getPickSet(this.selectedPickNumber, this.selectedRegion);
    console.log(this.currentPickSelection);
  }
}
```

The console.log prints out this data to the browser console
[image: Browser console data]

But the ngFor in the below doesn't pick up any data from the "currentPickSelection" array.

```
<ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" align="right" >
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let channels of currentPickSelection">
            <strong><font size="2">{{ channels.channel }}</font><span class="w3-right"><font size="2">{{ channels.pickCode }}</font></span></strong>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Please advise! thanks

Comment: Can you share sample json response in this question ?`console.log(JSON.stringify(this.currentPickSelection));`   share data log will be printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html looks incorrect.
You have an array (which you use `*ngFor` on) with arrays inside that contain objects. Therefore you need to first access the object in each `channels` and then the props.

```
<ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" align="right" >
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let channels of currentPickSelection">
         <strong><font size="2">{{ channels[0].channel }}</font><span class="w3-right"><font size="2">{{ channels[0].pickCode }}</font></span></strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested ngFor since your channels is again an array

```
  <ul *ngFor="let channels of currentPickSelection">
        <li *ngFor="let channel of channels">
              <strong><font size="2">{{ channel.channel }}</font><span class="w3-right"><font size="2">{{ channel.pickCode }}</font></span></strong>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: GetPickSet is a service that I created, not pulling any data from the web. And I am also getting all the data into that array, but the ngfor doesn't pull any of it.

Comment: try this <h1>     <strong><font size="2">{{ channels?.channel }}</font><span class="w3-right"><font size="2">{{ channels?.pickCode }}</font></span></strong> </h1>

Comment: @vicbyte tbh i dint see your answer ! i was looking what was wrong , after seeing OPs screenshot i edited. even now your answer is different from mine i would say

Comment: Thanks vicbyte. That worked. I had objects inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent {
  pickBtnClicked = false;
  selectedPickNumber: 'string';
  selectedRegion: 'string';
  currentPickSelection: any[];
  channelList: any[];

  constructor(private pickGroupService: PickGroupService, private channelsService: ChannelsService) {}

  onPkClick(btnPicked) {
    this.pickBtnClicked = true;
    this.selectedPickNumber = btnPicked;
  }
  onRegionClick(regionPicked) {
    this.selectedRegion = regionPicked;
    this.currentPickSelection = this.pickGroupService.getPickSet(this.selectedPickNumber, this.selectedRegion);
    console.log(this.currentPickSelection);
this.keysofdata = Object.keys(this.currentPickSelection) <---can get keys
  }
}

ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" align="right" >
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let channels of currentPickSelection;let i = index;">
            <strong><font size="2">{{ currentPickSelection[i][i].channel  }}</font><span class="w3-right"><font size="2">{{currentPickSelection[i][i].pickCode }}</font></span></strong>
          </li>
        </ul>
```